# Java Why T is still calling default method when T extends the interface

Tags: java, static, static-methods

```
public class Draw<T extends Print> (Print is a interface)
```

Other classes:

```
public interface Print {
    static void info(String message) {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
 }
public class Test implements Print {
    static void info(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

When use `new Draw<Test>()` and try to run T.info("Test");
it only printed "failed"

Am I did anything wrong?

Comment: Static explicitly indicate you want this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods don’t get overridden. You have to call Test.info to call your method.
Static methods are on interfaces because it’s a convenient place to put them. It’s not something you can override, and it’s not a default method. Default methods aren’t static, and you have to use the default keyword.

If you want polymorphism, use instance methods, not static ones.